# Invalid syntax with conditional expressions

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, wsgi, django-wsgi

It's all started from installing new python version, 2.7.5. I get this error when WSGI runs my django's wsgi.py file:

```
[Tue Sep 03 23:25:42 2013] [error] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] mod_wsgi (pid=4710): Target WSGI script '/var/www/empirik/data/www/mysite.com/my_project/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Sep 03 23:25:42 2013] [error] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] mod_wsgi (pid=4710): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/empirik/data/www/mysite.com/my_project/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Sep 03 23:25:42 2013] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Sep 03 23:25:42 2013] [error]   File "/var/www/empirik/data/www/mysite.com/my_project/wsgi.py", line 22, in ?
[Tue Sep 03 23:25:42 2013] [error]     import os
[Tue Sep 03 23:25:42 2013] [error]   File "/home/envs/my_project/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 49, in ?
[Tue Sep 03 23:25:42 2013] [error]     import posixpath as path
[Tue Sep 03 23:25:42 2013] [error]   File "/home/envs/my_project/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 324
[Tue Sep 03 23:25:42 2013] [error]     slash, dot = (u'/', u'.') if isinstance(path, _unicode) else ('/', '.')
[Tue Sep 03 23:25:42 2013] [error]                                ^
[Tue Sep 03 23:25:42 2013] [error] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I use virtualenv and can't figure out why it happens. I have python 2.4.3 also installed on this machine but it's not even associated with "python" alias and there's definitely python 2.7.5 in my virtualenv.

**UPDATE:**
Ok, I've raised exception in my wsgi.py to see sys.path which it uses and it's python2.4:

```
['/home/envs/my_env/lib/python24.zip', '/home/envs/my_env/lib/python2.4/', '/home/envs/my_env/lib/python2.4/plat-linux2', '/home/envs/my_env/lib/python2.4/lib-tk', '/home/envs/my_env/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload']
```

I don't understand why and how can I change it to python2.7.

Comment: Can you print the source where that error originates from? Looks like a simple syntax error to me, as the error message states.

Comment: What is the line that *precedes* this? You most likely forgot to close a parenthesis, bracket or brace somewhere before.

Comment: Try making a `collections.Counter`, just to check that this really is 2.7.5.

Comment: Ternary expression was added in py2.5, make sure you're on py2.7 only. What does `which python` returns in your virtualenv?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, /home/envs/my_env/bin/python... And when i run this, it says that this is python 2.7.5.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, You mean whole traceback? I've updated the question now.

Comment: Try to print `import sys; print(sys.version_info)` inside the script. Maybe you aren't using the correct interpreter. The error seem to come from a stdlib module, which shouldn't be possible if the versions of the interpreter and the stdlib match.

Comment: @Bakuriu, I've done it. Please look at the question update.

Comment: @DmitryMikhaylov: That looks a lot like Python 2.4 trying to load Python 2.7 library code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yes. I tried to append path /home/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7 to sys.path in wsgi.py file. When I removed it - ImportError for os module returned as I described in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578109/no-module-named-os-with-wsgi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear your mod_wsgi is compiled for and uses Python 2.4. You cannot take a mod_wsgi built for one Python version and force it to use a runtime installation for a different version. Go check the state of the your mod_wsgi and what it is compiled for.

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation